# how to make footer visible at bottom of window if content is less

Tags: jquery, css

HTML

```
<div class="header">logo</div>
<div class="some-content">some content</div>
<div class="footer">Footer here</div>
```

In a div with class name 'some-content', If it has more content footer is visible at the bottom of window, but if content is less, footer jumps up where the content block end, How to fix this up.

Comment: Google for "sticky footer".

Comment: post your css and let SO know what you have tried to make your footer "visible at the bottom of window".

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the question properly, but if you want the footer to be always at a fixed position i.e, the bottom of browser then you can use the below styling

```
 <div class="header">logo</div>
<div class="some-content">some content</div>
<div class="footer" style="position:absolute;top:95%;width:100%;background-color:orange;">Footer here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.. check comments

```css
/**** required CSS ***/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
/* browser reset */

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* height of footer */
}
body {
  height: 100%:
}
/* height of footer */

footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
/* DEMO Styling */

footer {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  soemthing which doesn't covers whole page
  <footer>copyright and I stay at bottoms always</footer>
</body>
```